# Why div id="in" not stay in side div id="out" , on this code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Why div id="in" not stay in side div id="out" , on this code ?

when load page `base.php` it's will show like this

```
<div id="out" style=" position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 999; "></div>
<div id="in" style=" display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 999; height: 40px; background-color: #00818C;">test</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dy0Lgcy/

But i want like this

```
<div id="out" style=" position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 999; ">
    <div id="in" style=" display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 999; height: 40px; background-color: #00818C;">test</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6dy0Lgcy/1/

How can i do that ?

base.php

```
<?php
  include('add_on.php');
  $number = '12345';
  test($number);
?>
```

add_on.php

```
<div id="out" style=" position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 999; ">
<?php
  function test($numeric)
  {
    if($numeric != '')
    {
?>
    <div id="in" style=" display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 999; height: 40px; background-color: #00818C;">
        test
    </div>
<?PHP
    }
  }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you not just amend the HTML as you need? What do you mean by 'not stay inside'?

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan - i update my question.

Comment: Put your `out` div in `base.php` file.

Comment: Since you don't call `test()` until AFTER you include the file, any output performed in that file will be done first, THEN the output from your function.

Answer (score 1):

change your function like this because function always returns instead of print

```
function test($numeric){
   $data = '<div id="out" style=" position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 999; ">';
    if($numeric != ''){
    $data.= '<div id="in" style=" display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 999; height: 40px; background-color: #00818C;">
        test
    </div>';
    }
    $data.= '</div>';
    return $data;
  }
```

and call it like this

```
$number = '12345';
echo test($number);
```

Answer (score 0):

The add_on.php file should be:

```
<?php
  function test($numeric)
  {
    ?><div id="out" style=" position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 999; "><?PHP
    if($numeric != '')
    {
?>
    <div id="in" style=" display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 999; height: 40px; background-color: #00818C;">
        test
    </div>
<?PHP
    }
    ?></div><?PHP
  }
?>
```

Comment: @ machineaddict - div id="out" must stay outside function.

Comment: Why do you need it outside that function?

Comment: @ machineaddict - in my use code div id="out" will cover many div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code In **add_on.php**

```
<?php
  function test($numeric){
  if($numeric != ''){
    echo '<div id="in" style=" display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 999; height: 40px; background-color: #00818C;">test</div>';
    }
  }
?>
```

**base.php**

```
<?php
    include('add_on.php');
    echo '<div id="out" style=" position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 999; ">';
    $number = '12345';
    test($number);
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: @ Vijay S - div id="out" must stay outside function.

Comment: @robertderfolo i have update my answer.. Now  div id="out" is out side of the function.

Comment: but div id="out" must stay in add_on.php

Answer (score 0):

Although all answers are true, none explain what's the real problem. In your `add_on.php`, you initiate a function. But if the function echo some text, it will not be echoed where the function is initiated, but where it is called.

So when you use `include('add_on.php');` you're just adding the file that contain a function declaration. However, there is HTML not included in the function. That HTML is directly *"echoed"*. You then call the function that echo the other `div`.

If you can't include the first `div` in the function (as stated in your comments). I suggest you to not use a function at all. Just set your variable first and then include :

## PHP

```
<?php
  $number = '12345';
  include('add_on.php');
?>
```

## add_on.php

```
<div id="out" style=" position: fixed; width: 100%; z-index: 999; ">
<?php
    if($number != '')
    {
?>
    <div id="in" style=" display: block; width: 100%; position: relative; z-index: 999; height: 40px; background-color: #00818C;">
        test
    </div>
<?PHP
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Karl-André Gagnon - i must to use function like my question,

Comment: My first question is: why? If you use a function you'll need to use something like `ob_start`